# Getting Info from GCP Data Catalog

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I notice when you query the data catalog in the Google Cloud Platform it retrieves stats for the amount of times a table has been queried:

```
Queried (Past 30 days): 5332
```

This is extremely useful information and I was wondering where this is actually stored and if it can be retrieved for all the tables in a project or a dataset.

I have trawled the data catalog tutorials and written some python scripts but these just retrieve entry names for tables and in an iterator which is not what I am looking for.

Likewise I also cannot see this data in the information schema metadata.

Comment: Can you please detail where do you see/obtain that information on Data Catalog?

Comment: It is availble in BigQuery table details page in Data catalog

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the number of completed/performed queries of any table/dataset [exporting log entries to BiqQuery](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2). Every query generates some logging on Stackdriver so you can use [advanced filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) to select the logs you are interested it and store them as a new table in Bigquery.

However, [the retention period for the data access logs in GCP is 30 days](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods), so you can only export the logs in the past 30 days.

For instance, use the following advance filter for getting the logs corresponding to all the jobs completed of an specific table:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource" AND
log_name="projects/<project_name>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access" AND
proto_payload.method_name="jobservice.jobcompleted"
"<table_name>"
```

Then select Bigquery as Sink Service and state a name for your sink table and the dataset where it will be stored.

All the completed jobs on this table performed after the sink is established will appear as a new table in BigQuery. You can query this table to get information about the logs (you can use a COUNT statement on any column to get the total number of successful jobs for instance).

Comment: Occasional voting advice is OK in the comments, though it is better to advise people to accept/upvote _an_ answer, rather than yours specifically. We would rather not have it in posts though, which should concentrate on question/answer material. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, I will take it into account for the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This information is available in the projects.locations.entryGroups.entries/get API. It is availble as UsageSignal, and contains usage information of 24 hours, 7days, 30days.

**Sample output:**

```
"usageSignal": {
    "updateTime": "2021-05-23T06:59:59.971Z",
    "usageWithinTimeRange": {
      "30D": {
        "totalCompletions": 156890,
        "totalFailures": 3,
        "totalCancellations": 1,
        "totalExecutionTimeForCompletionsMillis": 6.973312e+08
      },
      "7D": {
        "totalCompletions": 44318,
        "totalFailures": 1,
        "totalExecutionTimeForCompletionsMillis": 2.0592365e+08
      },
      "24H": {
        "totalCompletions": 6302,
        "totalExecutionTimeForCompletionsMillis": 25763162
      }
    }
  }
```

**Reference:**

https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.entryGroups.entries/get

https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.entryGroups.entries#UsageSignal

Answer (score 0):

With Python Datacatalog - You first need to search the Data catalog and you will receive linked_resource in response.

Pass this linked_resource as a request to lookup_entry and you will fetch the last queried (30 days)

```
results = dc_client.search_catalog(request=request, timeout=120.0)
for result in results:
    linked_resource = result.linked_resource

    # Get the Location and number of times the table is queried in last 30 days
    table_entry = dc_client.lookup_entry(request={"linked_resource": linked_resource})

    queried_past_30_days = table_entry.usage_signal.usage_within_time_range.get("30D")
    if queried_past_30_days is not None:
        dc_num_queried_past_30_days = int(queried_past_30_days.total_completions)
    else:
        dc_num_queried_past_30_days = 0
```